# Joint density functions in Probability and statistics

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

[image]

Hi could anyone help me here. I am currently studying Probability and Statistics and I have just been introduced to the idea of Joint density functions. So for the question this is how far I have got:

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases}
 8xy& \text{if } 0< y < x < 1\\
0  &\text{otherwise},
\end{cases}$$

I know I need to find out firstly $(f_x|y)$ and $(f_y|x)$

With $(f_x|y)(x|y) = \frac{(f_(x,y)*(x,y)}{f_y*(y))}  = \frac{8xy}{?}$

here I'm not sure what should be on the bottom. I think maybe 8x?

and then secondly I need to find out secondly $(f_y|x)$

with $(f_y|x)(y|x) =  \frac{(f_(x,y)*(x,y)}{f_x*(x))}  = \frac{8xy}{?}$

and again I'm not quite sure what should be on the bottom. I think maybe 8y?

Any help on this would really be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> here I'm not sure what should be on the bottom. I think maybe 8x

the bivariate support is

$$0<\underbrace{y<x<1}_{X-Support}$$

Thus to derive $f_Y(y)$ you have to integrate the joint density over $X-$ support

$$f_Y(y)=\int_y^1 8xy dx=\dots=4y(1-y^2)\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(0;1)}(y)$$

Thus the conditional density is

$$f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{2x}{1-y^2}\mathbb{1}_{(y;1)}(x)$$

Thus, given that $Y=y=\frac{1}{3}$ you get

$$f_{X|Y=\frac{1}{3}}(t)=\frac{9}{4} t\cdot \mathbb{1}_{(\frac{1}{3};1)}(t)$$

Concluding,

The probability to have

$$\mathbb{P}\Bigg[X>\frac{3}{4}\Bigg|Y=\frac{1}{3}\Bigg]=\int_{\frac{3}{4}}^{1}\frac{9}{4} tdt=\frac{63}{128}\approx0.49$$

Comment: Thanks! could you tell me where the end bit comes from though? I'm not sure how you get the $1_(0;1)(y)$

Comment: @TaylorS. the joint support is $0<y<x<1$. When you integrate in $dx$ the rv $X$ " disappears" thus the marginal support of y is $(0;1)$. Read well all the passages I showed... I think they will clarify the situation. Otherwise let me know